# How can i use the AWS commands for Powershell in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, aws-powershell

I am trying to upload to use AWS cmds in a Jenkins job . It works fine if i run from Powershell on Windows , but once i run it from a Powershell step in a Jenkins job it gives an error :

```
Set-AWSCredentials : The term 'Set-AWSCredentials' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
```

Is it a priviledges thing or Jenkins logged in user permission?

Under the jenkins service I am logged on as a user on the machine that is administrator.

How can i get this to work ?

Comment: Can you import AWSPowershell module before running Set-AWSCredentials .
`Import-module AWSPowershell`